# Desktop Application SSRS Report Rendering Out Of Memory Exception on single user PC

Tags: c#, reporting-services, out-of-memory, ssrs-2008, desktop-application

We have a .NET desktop Application Running
One of my user is facing **OutOfMemory** **Exception** while **SSRS Report Rendering**
Though, I am able to run SSRS through Browser Report Link.

All other users are working fine

User PC Configuration
i5 10th Gen 8 GB Ram (Lot of free space Available)

Steps performed

1. Tried Reinstalling Application
2. Tried Deleting Temp Files
3. Checked TaskManager  everything is ok

Is there any thing else why ??

Below is the Error Screenshot i am facing..

[image]

Comment: _"Checked TaskManager everything is ok"_ - how much memory is it using?  If it's a 32-bit app then the maximum it can use is ~1.5 GB RAM.

Comment: seems to me that you are loading large dataset and the desktop runs out of ram. Try to load only what is needed to display

Comment: @MickyD Its a 32 BIT Application running on 64 bit sytem. 50% of memory is empty

Comment: @MickyD "maximum it can use is ~1.5 GB RAM" Can i increase it on single user level system

Comment: @Demon No a single liner Report is also giving me same error.

Comment: The query syntax may be causing the error.  Try running the query string in SSMS and see if you get any errors.  Also check the SQL Server log file for errors.   It looks like you are using Entity and there is an issue with the mapping between the database and the c# classes.  A type may not be matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reporting Services were ok , as well as report was also ok

**The Problem was with Users Hard Disk**

My Infra Team Replaced the Hard disk

And the error was resolved

Answer (score 1):

This situation will occur when one of the following conditions are true :

- The report is too large or complex.
- The overhead of other running processes is very high.
- The physical memory of computer is too small.

You can reduce memory consumption by redesigning the report queries:

- Return less data in the queries.(you can add filter parameter)
- Use a better restriction on the WHERE clause.
- Move complex aggregations to the data source or view.
- Increase sufficient physical memory to the computer.
- Adjust MemoryLimit setting accordingly.

For more information about `System.OutOfMemoryException` and Configuring Available Memory for Report Server Applications, please refer to the articles below:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909678/EN-US
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159206.aspx